Unable to Resize Circle and Stretch Rectangle with Leaflet Draw's EditControl in React-Leaflet
I'm working with react-leaflet and react-leaflet-draw to create and edit shapes on a map. I can draw circles and rectangles, but I'm experiencing two specific issues:
1. I can't resize the circle after it’s drawn: Although the move handler works, the resize handles for the circle don’t seem to function properly.
2. I can't stretch the rectangle while drawing it: However, after the rectangle is drawn, I can resize and move it as expected.
import {
  MapContainer,
  TileLayer,
  Marker,
  Popup,
  useMap,
  FeatureGroup,
} from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css";
import L from "leaflet";
import { FullscreenControl } from "react-leaflet-fullscreen";
import "react-leaflet-fullscreen/styles.css";
const EditControl = React.lazy(async () => {
  const module = await import("react-leaflet-draw");
  return { default: module.EditControl };
});

// @ts-ignore
import icon from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png";
// @ts-ignore
import iconShadow from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png";
let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: icon,
  shadowUrl: iconShadow,
  iconAnchor: [12, 41],
});
L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon;

const ChangeMapView = ({ center }) => {
  const map = useMap();
  useEffect(() => {
    map.setView(center);
  }, [center, map]);
  return null;
};

const Map = () => {
  const [sensors, setSensors] = useState([]);
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState([0, 0]);
  const [sensorsInCircle, setSensorsInCircle] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/sensors")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setSensors(data);
        if (data.length > 0) {
          const { latitude, longitude } = data[0];
          setMapCenter([latitude, longitude]);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error("Error fetching data:", err));
  }, []);

  const onShapeCreated = (e) => {
    const { layer, layerType } = e;
  
    if (layerType === "circle") {
      const radius = layer.getRadius();
      const center = layer.getLatLng();
  
      const sensorsInRange = sensors.filter((sensor) => {
        const sensorLatLng = L.latLng(sensor.latitude, sensor.longitude);
        return sensorLatLng.distanceTo(center) <= radius;
      });
  
      setSensorsInCircle(sensorsInRange);
      alert(`Sensors in circle: ${sensorsInRange.length}`);
    }
  
    if (layerType === "rectangle") {
      const bounds = layer.getBounds();
  
      const sensorsInRectangle = sensors.filter((sensor) => {
        const sensorLatLng = L.latLng(sensor.latitude, sensor.longitude);
        return bounds.contains(sensorLatLng);
      });
  
      setSensorsInCircle(sensorsInRectangle);
      alert(`Sensors in rectangle: ${sensorsInRectangle.length}`);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    // @ts-ignore
    <MapContainer center={mapCenter} zoom={10} scrollWheelZoom={true} style={{ height: "500px", width: "100%" }}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        // @ts-ignore
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <FullscreenControl position="topleft" />
      <ChangeMapView center={mapCenter} /> {/* Component to change map view */}
      <FeatureGroup>
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <EditControl
            position="topright"
            draw={{
              polyline: false,
              circlemarker: false,
              marker: {
                icon: DefaultIcon
              },
              rectangle: {
                shapeOptions: {
                  color: '#ff7800',
                  weight: 1,
                },
              },
            }}
            onCreated={onShapeCreated}
          />
        </React.Suspense>
      </FeatureGroup>
      {sensors.map((sensor) => (
        <Marker
          key={sensor.deviceId}
          position={[sensor.latitude, sensor.longitude]}
        >
          <Popup>
            <b>Device ID:</b> {sensor.deviceId} <br />
            <b>Description:</b> {sensor.description} <br />
            <b>Dimming Level:</b> {sensor.dimmingLevel}
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default Map;

I am using the latest versions of the required libraries, but I suspect there may be an incompatibility between leaflet-draw and react-leaflet-draw. Specifically, leaflet-draw does not seem to be correctly imported, as this part of the code is not explicitly declared and triggers an error in the server console.
